# Are Asians considered "marginalized groups" on the Stack Exchange network?

Tags: discussion

I was just curious: are Asians, e.g. Chinese, Indian, Asian Americans, considered a "marginalized group" or a minority voice at Stack Overflow and elsewhere around the SE network?

Or does "people of color and women" really mean "black people and women"?

Comment: Especially for having a growing software industry, these should probably rather called ***majorized group*** s.

Comment: I think the selection of those words is deliberate to not rule out any group. So I'm pretty sure it doesn't really mean *black people*

Comment: What are you doing to do with an answer? Congratulate yourself for being in a marginalized group? Tell someone else they are not marginalized? I don't understand why this is a thing to ask. If someone feels excluded, they feel excluded. Proving they are or are not is not necessary.

Comment: @kategregory - I dunno what I would do with an answer, but I wasn't planning on congratulating myself, chill out.  I just like things clearly defined, given my training in mathematics, perhaps.  You say "feel excluded", I am asking about the terms "marginalized group" and "people of color", so you are obfuscating details, whether you intend to or not.  If the terms I am asking about cannot be clearly defined, that's fine too - that's the point of my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a red herring. The problem isn't whether some group or another feels unwelcome (though we have empirical evidence some groups feel less welcome than others). Rather, the problem is various aspects of the sites make people who already feel marginalized feel *even more marginalized*. That's what we gotta fix.

Personally, I've worked with fine programmers who aren't interested in participating on Stack Overflow because they are afraid of the site. Each of them would raise the average quality of questions if they were willing to ask, so it's a shame we actively discourage them. If the thing that finally gets us to work on this problem is the experience of a specific group, that's fine by me. As long as we finally get around to doing what's needed doing for years.

And if we can make a dent on Stack Overflow, that work will pay dividends on other sites too.

Comment: _"Personally, I've worked with fine programmers who aren't interested in participating on Stack Overflow because they are afraid of the site."_ For starters: As newbies, we should teach them how to use the particular sites using the [tour] (<= symbolic). I ever used Stack Overflow as **the valuable resource** for solving my particular (maybe tech edge case) problemz, and never found that kind of _toxiticity_ or _marginalizing_ which is the recent hype about here. You're in charge to change a lot of cultural problems (similar as facebook is currently forced to do): Good luck with the project

Comment: (no sarcasm, just fullheartedly good luck)

Comment: "*If the thing that finally gets us to work on this problem is the experience of a specific group, that's fine by me.*" The solution to the "experience of a specific group" will *not* be the solution to the problem of general discouragement. [These are separate issues, and need to be resolved separately.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366665/734069) People who feel marginalized feeling more marginalized is irrelevant to being unwelcoming to people in general.

Comment: What do you mean by "various aspects of the sites make people who already feel marginalized feel even more marginalized"? It's still not clear to me why anyone (with the exception of the noob demographic) is feeling marginalized—Are they being targeted for being a minority? Is it unintentional marginalization (such as assuming male pronouns)? Is it just part of a larger thing (e.g. noobs of all types feeling unwelcome)? Something else?

Comment: @Laurel: I wrote about it [in this blog post](http://jericson.github.io/2018/03/23/race_to_1k_6.html): "That first interaction with a community sets a tone that’s very hard to change. What’s worse is that many people are predisposed to seeing condescending comments on our site. Changing that perception will require people consistently going out of their way to be welcoming." It's sorta a through-the-looking-glass situation. On one side, the interactions are perfectly reasonable. From the other, they are aggressive and antagonistic.

Comment: @JonEricson : Always a pleasure finding out about a high rep SO user such as yourself, who actually wants to help other people and not his or her ego. If I can help you in any way in this issue - please contact me.

Comment: @RannLifshitz: [Fill out the survey!](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSdCQNtu4KHesQz-2AzRSl8z6d4_cLgPj4B7cjNpPePc-04seA/formResponse) Thanks for the kind words.